# To tokenize the values in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, stringtokenizer

I have a map whcih has the key value  as long and value as String. The values of the map are obtained from the db and it is in the below format.

```
1: BusinessPartner.name1,BusinessPartner.name2,BusinessPartner.name3,BusinessPartner.name4
2: BusinessPartner.name1,BusinessPartner.name2,BusinessPartner.name3
6: ADDRESS.addressline1,ADDRESS.addressline2,ADDRESS.addressline3
```

where 1,2,6 are the keys.

I need to tokenize the strings that is for the key 1 the result should be 
Businesspartner and the other values should be name1,name2,name3,name4.
I am doing this because i need to put these values into an another map as 
Map(name1,name2,name3,name4)>
I can split the string but how to take Businesspartner as a common value for the other entities

Can anybody tell me how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would this work for your riquierment ?

```
public class Tokenize {

    static Long keysFromDB[] = {1L, 2L, 6L};
    static String stringsFromDB[] = {
        "BusinessPartner.name1,BusinessPartner.name2,BusinessPartner.name3,BusinessPartner.name4",
        "BusinessPartner.name1,BusinessPartner.name2,BusinessPartner.name3",
        "ADDRESS.addressline1,ADDRESS.addressline2,ADDRESS.addressline3"};

    @Test
    public void tokenize() {
        // use linked hashmap to preserve the order
        Map<Long, Set<String>> tokenized = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Set<String>>();
        int c = 0;
        for(Long key : keysFromDB) {
            // use linked hashset to preserve the order
            Set<String> record = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            String splitedDBStrings[] = stringsFromDB[c++].split("\\.|,");
            System.out.println("List: " + Arrays.asList(splitedDBStrings));
            for(String s : splitedDBStrings) {
                record.add(s);
            }
            System.out.println("Set:  " + record);
            tokenized.put(key, record);
        }

        System.out.println(tokenized);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from the beginning:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[,\\s*]?([^.]+)\\.([^,]+)[,\\s*]?");
final Map<Long, String> myMap = getMapFromSomewhere();    

for(final Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
  final String myString = entry.getValue(); 
  final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);      
  final Map<String, List<String>> tokenised = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
  while (matcher.find()) {
    final String key = matcher.group(1);
    List<String> names = tokenised.get(key);
    if(names == null) {
       names = new LinkedList<String>();
       tokenised.put(key, names)
    }
    names.add(matcher.group(2));
  }
  //do stuff with map.
}
```

The regex breaks down as follows:

- `[,\\s*]?` optionally matches a comma followed by whitespace of unknown (or zero) length
- `([^.]+)\\.` matches everything up to the next stop followed by a "."
- `([^,]+)` takes everything upto the next comma in a match group
- `[,\\s*]?` optionally matches a comma followed by whitespace of unknown (or zero) length

Test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[,\\s*]?([^.]+)\\.([^,]+)[,\\s*]?");

    final String myString = "BusinessPartner.name1,BusinessPartner.name2,BusinessPartner.name3,BusinessPartner.name4";
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BusinessPartner
name1
BusinessPartner
name2
BusinessPartner
name3
BusinessPartner
name4
```

Comment: i think he wants `BusinessPartner` and `ADDRESS` (the string witch is repeating) to be part of the result

Comment: i think he wants it only one time, he writes `the result should be Businesspartner and the other values should be name1,name2,name3,name4.` thus `BusinessPartner,name1,name2,name3,name4`

Answer (score 0):

run this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<Long, String> dbmap = new HashMap<Long, String>();
    dbmap.put((long) 1, "BusinessPartner.name1,BusinessPartner.name2,BusinessPartner.name3,BusinessPartner.name4");
    dbmap.put((long) 2, "BusinessPartner.name1,BusinessPartner.name2,BusinessPartner.name3");
    dbmap.put((long) 6, "ADDRESS.addressline1,ADDRESS.addressline2,ADDRESS.addressline3");

    //Loop through the Map
    Iterator<Entry<Long, String>> iterator = dbmap.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){

        Map.Entry<Long, String> entry = (Map.Entry<Long, String>) iterator.next();

        //Split the string on comma ','
        //result entries should be 'BusinessPartner.name1', 'BusinessPartner.name2' etc
        String[] commaSplit = entry.getValue().split(",");

        //loop through each entry
        for(int x=0; x<commaSplit.length; x++){

            //Split on Full Stop
            //Result should be 'BusinessPartner', 'name2'
            String[] dotSplit = commaSplit[x].split("\\.");

            //print out common Value
            System.out.println("Common Value is : " + dotSplit[0]);

            //print out second value
            System.out.println("Second Value is : " + dotSplit[1]);

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

output is something like this

> ```
> Common Value is : BusinessPartner
> Second Value is : name1
>
> Common Value is : BusinessPartner
> Second Value is : name2
>
> Common Value is : BusinessPartner
> Second Value is : name3
>
> Common Value is : BusinessPartner
> Second Value is : name4
>
> Common Value is : BusinessPartner
> Second Value is : name1
>
> Common Value is : BusinessPartner
> Second Value is : name2
>
> Common Value is : BusinessPartner
> Second Value is : name3
>
> Common Value is : ADDRESS
> Second Value is : addressline1
>
> Common Value is : ADDRESS
> Second Value is : addressline2
>
> Common Value is : ADDRESS
> Second Value is : addressline3
> ```

Comment: Thank you Friends for ur reply