# Java String Tokenize from backwards

Tags: java, string

I have a string

```
ContactPerson.BusinessPartner.name1,ContactPerson.BusinessPartner.name2,ContactPerson.fullname
```

Here i need to break the string based on comma and i have done that

```
ContactPerson.BusinessPartner.name1
ContactPerson.BusinessPartner.name2
ContactPerson.fullname
```

But i need to tokenize this again from the end that is i need to extract name1 and should store it corresponding to Businesspartner.Same case for name 2.It should be stored corresponding to the Busineespartner. For fullname also i should extract fullname and store to corresponding contactperson.So what i need is i should split the string from backwards where i encounter the (.) first and should split the string into two and store the string corresponding to the String before. The example i gave is simple. Normally we get

Strings like 
Contactperson.Customer.Company.Businesspartner.name1 etc
so name1 should be stored correspndingly to th businesspartner.
Can anybody help me how to do this any idea??

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270299/to-tokenize-the-values-in-a-hashmap/15270932#15270932 you asked the same question yesterday. didn't that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last parts like this:

```
String input = "ContactPerson.BusinessPartner.name1,ContactPerson.BusinessPartner.name2,ContactPerson.fullname";
String[] parts = input.split(",");
for (String part : parts) {
    String[] subparts = part.split("\\.");
    String last = subparts[subparts.length - 1];
}
```

`last` will then contain `name1`, `name2`, ...

See [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String s = "ContactPerson.BusinessPartner.name1";
    String name = s.replaceAll(".+\\.([^.]+)", "$1");
```